# Matlab error - Matrix dimensions must agree

Tags: matlab, matrix

```
cc=imread('<a href=“http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/d/d6/Pavlovsk_Railing_of_bridge_Yellow_palace_Winter.jpg/250px-Pavlovsk_Railing_of_bridge_Yellow_palace_Winter.jpg”>wintersm.jpg</a>'); 
c=rgb2gray(cc);
x=ones(256,1)*[1:256];
c2=double(c).*(x/2+50)+(1-double(c)).*x/2;
c3=uint8(255*mat2gray(c2));
t=graythresh(c3);
ct=im2bw(c3,t);
```

This is a code i have written to threshold the image but cant execute because of the error " ==> times
Matrix dimensions must agree. "  . I am new to matlab and i cant figure out how to solve this problem. Please Help.

Comment: what is the size of matrix `c`. And in which line you are getting this error ?

Comment: It means one of your operations have different/incompatible matrix dimensions. What line are you getting the error?

Comment: What do you think that the `double(c)` is doing?

Comment: I am getting the error after the line where c3 is defined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I looked at the image, it is of size `169x250` . Hence `size(c) = [169 250]` while `size(x) = [256 256]`. Since `.*` operation between `c` and `x` needs both of them to be of same size , hence it is giving the error.

Redefine `x` so that its size matches the size of `c`

Answer (score 1):

I ran your code but added the following line before `c2=double(c).*(x/2+50)+(1-double(c)).*x/2;`, I added this:

```
size(x)
size(c)
```

and you get the following print out:

```
ans =
  256   256
ans =
  169   250
```

Which is essentially saying, the image isnt the size you think it is and you are mixing your matrix sizes.